# Cordova: Samsung S3 not recognized via USB on Mac

Tags: android, macos, cordova, device

I have a basic Hello World Cordova application working on an Android emulator (Nexus 4) on my Mac.  I wanted to try deploying to a Samsung Galaxy S3 that I have (model SCH-R530M) but when I try running `adb devices` and empty list is returned.

I have already tried unplugging the device, killing adb using `adb kill-server`, running adb using `adb start-server`, and then plugging the device back in and it is still not being recognized.

The only other problem I can find is that my USB cable might be a "charge only" cable, but I don't know how I would go about determining if it is.

Does anyone have a potential fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it in developer mode?

Does it allow USB debugging?
https://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

These are the instructions for your device:
https://muffinresearch.co.uk/samsung-galaxy-s3-where-are-the-developer-options/

Go to Settings → More → About Device
Scroll down to Build Number
Tap it repeatedly (It'll show a message telling you how many more times you need to tap it to enable developer mode).
See the Developer options menu under Settings → More

Then make sure 'usb debugging' is selected in the developer options.

Comment: The developer mode is on on the phone. Neither Cordova or Android Studio is recognizing that a device is present even though the device is connected and charging.

Comment: Make sure it is directly connected to the machine. Do you see it in the 'System Information' application?

When I look I see my device named Nexus 7: http://i.imgur.com/Fd1Hrr3.png

Comment: If your phone is not connecting this is the right answer.  You also have to make sure that your computer and phone are able to "communicate".  When you plug the phone in it should ask if the computer can be trusted (authorized).  I have also had issues with node 5, so use node 4 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a different USB cables too. I had to try a couple before it would register the device.

Kies can also sometimes kickstart it.
http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/